# Processing multiple forms with individual submits

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to setup a product page, with multiple products etc... It is done through a while loop getting the data from a mysql database, the products display fine, but the problem i am having is that i want to be able to process each product individually, In other words, i don't know what products may be appearing on the page, so when i try to process them through php, it needs to be flexible. Its a bit hard to explain but here is my current code, hopefully you will see what i mean.

Here is my html for one individual product, all the products get ouputed like the code below

```
 <form id="<?php print "$material_id";?>" class="form">    
      <div class="supp_bro_mat_wrap">    
            <input type="hidden" name="supp_bro_mat_id" value="<?php print "$material_id";?>" />        
            <input name="supp_bro_qty_input" class="supp_bro_qty_input" type="text" />              
      </div><!---end supp_bro_input_wrap--->
            <input name="supp_bro_add_to_cart" type="submit" class="supp_bro_add_to_cart" id="<?php print "$material_id";?>" />          
 </form>
```

And here is the php code, simple i know, but i just want to be able to get the values at this stage,

```
 if (isset($_POST['supp_bro_add_to_cart'])) {


    $mat_id = $_POST['supp_bro_mat_id'];
    $mat_qty = $_POST['supp_bro_qty_input'];

    var_dump($mat_id);
    var_dump($mat_qty);
}
```

And when i try to enter a quantity for the first product i get the right var_dumps appear, but when i try it on all the products below it i get

```
supplies_browse.php?supp_bro_mat_id=5&supp_bro_qty_input=8768&supp_bro_add_to_cart=Submit
```

appear in my browser header instead of

```
supplies_browse.php?sid=masonary
```

Like it should be and no var_dumps. Hopefully you will get what i mean, let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks

Comment: what is the method of your forms? GET or POST?

Comment: arken i think you want to submit single product at a time or each product have there individual form right ??

Comment: What you mean by "when i try it on all the products below it". From your code it is clear that you have seperate submit button for each product. So at a time you can submit only one product. So how you can do it for all the products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not easy to tell from what you've posted, but it looks like you have an additional `<form>` tag in your HTML that precedes the products list. This additional `<form>` tag has `method="POST"` on it.

Because of this, on your products list, the `<form>` tag of the first product is being ignored (form elements are not allowed to be nested) so submitting the first product performs a POST submit, so the data gets transferred in the HTTP body, the URL has the value that you want, and your `$_POST` variables get populated correctly.

The `</form>` tag at the end of the first product then closes the additional `<form>`, and the second product and subsequent products are created in their own forms. The `<form>` tags for these have no method attribute specified, so the default method is used which is GET. This sends the information on the URL, which will not populate the $_POST variables.

The solution is to remove the additional `<form>` tag from the start of your page, and move the `method="POST"` attribute (and probably any other attributes on that tag) to each of the `<form>` tags for the products.